# PC が文字を表示する仕組み

Tags: linux

PC では以下のように文字が表示されることがわかりました。

ユーザー空間

ソフトウェア（echoなど）

↓ /dev/pts/1→(ptmx)ターミナル→x window system client

- カーネル空間

x server(open /dev/fb...)

↓

デバイスドライバ

↓

ビデオカード

Linux を使用している場合、[Videocard UTF-8 に従って指定された文字コードから文字を出力します。]

ちなみに、ビデオカードが使用する文字コード（utf-8とかsjisとか…）はカーネル起動時に初期化されて設定されると思います。

私の上記の考えは正しいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

> ちなみに、ビデオカードが使用する文字コード（utf-8とかsjisとか…）はカーネル起動時に初期化されて設定されると思います。

ちょっとちがいます
イマドキでは、ビデオカード側に文字出力の機能は持っていません
すべて、OS、あるいはデバイスドライバ側で、文字パターンを展開し、画像データとしてビデオカードに送ります。ビデオカード側では画像パターンを出力する機能しか持ちません

むかしむかし、MS-DOSの時代であれば、ビデオカード側で文字パターンデータを持ち、PC側は文字データをビデオカードに送ることで文字表示を行う、という時代もありました。

Comment: もう少し掘り下げて頂きたいです！

xserverが/dev/fbに書き込み、コールバックでデバドラが呼び出され、ビデオカードに画像データを送信するのか、
xserverからデバドラに移り、デバドラが/dev/fbのコールバックを呼び、映った先からビデオカードに画像データを送信するのか、
ここらへんのプロセスの順番はどういう風になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: あなたの言う xserver とはなんですか？ ホスティングサービス (レンタルサーバ)？

Comment: window systemのことです。

Comment: 「イマドキでは、ビデオカード側に文字出力の機能は」 => [`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/support/articles/000005520/graphics.html) で VGAがでるなら文字データだけで表示可能なはずです。Ctrl+Alt+F3 みたいな操作でコンソールに切り替えれば, (使えるようなら)使えます